# allocating static memory for character pointer defined in struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, struct

I have structure with char pointer. I want to allocate static memory to this struct member. How can I do this?

Example:

```
struct my_data {
    int x;
    bool y;
    char *buf;
 };
```

How to assign 10 bytes static memory to this char pointer? I know malloc to assign dynamic memory allocation. Is this Ok?

```
struct my_data data;
char buffer[10];
data.buf = &buffer[0];
```

PS: I am not allowed to change this struct and use malloc to assign dynamic memory.

Comment: By static you mean that it should persist for the entire run-time of your program? And what you did is legal, but whether or not it's correct depends on your applications needs.

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be even simpler (array decays to pointer automatically):

```
data.buf = buffer;
```

note that `buffer` must have an ever-lasting lifetime or you have to make sure that it's not deallocated (i.e. routine where it is declared returns) while you're using it or referencing it.

Allocating from a subroutine and returning will cause underfined behaviour because memory will be deallocated on return.

For instance *don't* do this (as we often see in questions here):

```
struct my_data foo()
{
struct my_data data;
char buffer[10];
data.buf = &buffer[0];
return data;
}
int main()
{
   struct my_data d = foo(); // buffer is already gone
```

Bugs introduced by this kind of UB are nasty because the code seems to work for a while, until the unallocated buffer gets clobbered by another function call.